# MAC Elasticsearch snapshot location

Tags: elasticsearch

In MAC elasticsearch to build repository

```js
PUT http://localhost:9400/_snapshot/my_backup 
{
    "type": "fs", 
    "settings": {
        "location": "/Users/Edison/Elasticsearch/Repository" 
    }
}
```

My computer is MacOS

I don't understand , how setting my location path..

This is my error message:

```
{
   "error": "RepositoryException[[my_backup] failed to create repository]; nested: CreationException[Guice creation errors:\n\n1) Error injecting constructor, org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoryException: [my_backup] location [/Users/Edison/Elasticsearch/Repository] doesn't match any of the locations specified by path.repo because this setting is empty\n  at org.elasticsearch.repositories.fs.FsRepository.<init>(Unknown Source)\n  while locating org.elasticsearch.repositories.fs.FsRepository\n  while locating org.elasticsearch.repositories.Repository\n\n1 error]; nested: RepositoryException[[my_backup] location [/Users/Edison/Elasticsearch/Repository] doesn't match any of the locations specified by path.repo because this setting is empty]; ",
   "status": 500
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch nodes require a shared drive for each node to save to, this shared directory is what the location property is referring to.

The first task is to set up this shared storage, for example you could choose a straightforward NFS mount: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-12-04 Once you have a mounted directory on each node, you can then register your backup location.

Alternatively you can use a Samba share, for which this seems to be a guide for: http://vichargrave.com/creating-elasticsearch-snapshots/

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... My environment is MAC OS, not Linux, How I get starting? Thanks you.

Comment: @Edison1986 If you are only using your Mac for a single instance of Elasticsearch, create a folder locally to use as your repository and provide the path to it. /Users/Edison/Elasticsearch/Repository or wherever.

Comment: Check whether the user the elasticsearch user has permission to write to the /mount/backups/my_backup directory

Answer (score 1):

Error which I had faced,

**"repository_exception","reason":"[my_backup] location [/tmp/my_backup] doesn't match any of the locations specified by path.repo because this setting is empty"}}}**

Operating system Centos

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-33-207-201 config]$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup' -d '{
> "type": "fs",
> "settings": {
> "location": "/tmp/my_backup",
> "compress": true
> }
> }'
{"acknowledged":true}[ec2-user@ip-10-33-207-201 config]$
```

**Solution**

You need's to add the repository path to elasticsearch.yml file

```
path.repo: ["/tmp/my_backup"]
```

**Reference**
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html